# Debug windows app in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2017, windows, mobile-application, windows-phone-8-emulator

[image]I am new to windows app and sorry if my question is very basic. I have a windows app(basically a web app) . I would like to open it and see in a emulator now.

1. I have tried opening in Visual studio 2017. But i get debug error as (miDebuggerPath is not valid. I have installed the windows10 SDK.
2. Also I am unable to see the emulator option in my IDE(nt sure if I am using wrong version)
3. I also wonder if '.sln' file is the runnable file. It would be great if an one could help.

Comment: The .sln file is the solution file, is the one Visual Studio opens.

Comment: But when i open .sln i get error as file format not supported. attached screen shot in question

Comment: The error tells you that the file Medinet.csproj that is a project file can't be opened, the solution is ok, but you have a project with problems, check if your visual studio have installed the options you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .sln file is the solution file, is the one Visual Studio opens. 
The error tells you that the file Medinet.csproj that is a project file can't be opened, the solution is ok, but you have a project with problems, check if your visual studio have installed the options you need.

In visual studio open Tools -> Get tools and features and check you have all you need like the Universal Windows Platform development and so on.

[image]

Comment: Ya. It is installed.

Comment: No. Even though the tools are instaled ,still I am getting the same error when i open the .ssl file

Comment: When i still debug the code , ilots of symbols loaded examole('Code.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cryptsp.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Code.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rsaenh.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Code.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gpapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.)   *But later nothing happens. It is in running state. I am sorrry about my basic questions. Just breaking my head with this windows app

Comment: In debug I have options like Debug-ARM, Debug-Any CPU.. Any leads on which one I should use? Right now I am getting build fail.  error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework "WindowsPhoneApp,Version=v8.1" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed...

Comment: Maybe is better if you create from scratch a basic app, at least to test your system and check that things works on your computer before go to something more complex.

Comment: I have created a sample project and tried to run. Getting error like hyper-v component is not running. I am using mac and virtually windows10(not sure if that is the probln)

Comment: When i check my settings i get under "microsoft Hyper-v virtual machine bus provider" - "Windows cannot initialize the device driver for this hardware. (Code 37)
The request is not supported."

Comment: Have you enabled the hyper-V?, can you vote my answer?